# Add parent POM in Git project

Tags: java, git, maven, pom.xml

My project is Maven based I have one parent POM with many sub modules. In my case I have this directory tree:

```
Folder 1
  |--.git
  |--Module1
  |--Module2
```

I want to add several additional POM files like this:

```
New_Parent_POM
  |--Folder 1
  |    |--.git
  |    |--Module1
  |    |--Module2
  |
  |--New_Folder2
```

When I do this the .git folder which is used to store the objects is still into the old folder. Is it necessary to more it into the main directory? I tested to perform this but the new POM files are not found from Git? Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In a similar scenario I used a different approach, making one git repository for each project:

```
New_Parent_POM
   |--.git

Folder 1
   |--.git
   |--Module1
   |--Module2

New_Folder2
   |--.git

New_Folder3
   |--.git
```

In this way I can independently manage each project history and workflow.

I've set the parent pom using artifactId instead of path, but I think that something like this should work as well:

```
<relativePath>../New_Parent_POM/pom.xml</relativePath>
```

You can find more examples of maven project layouts in the [official guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).